# How to take Screenshot on MacosX and Linux in C / C++ Screenshot API and save it as Image

Tags: c++, c, api, unix, screenshot

Is there any professional way how to take a screenshot on Macos and Linux (they don’t need to have the same API ;)).

After some research I managed to do one using gnome - screenshot on terminal, but that’s not the professional way I would like to ;(

Regards, from Brooks ;)

Comment: It varies between operating systems and desktop environments. It will be different for MacOS, Linux using X11, Linux using Wayland, Linux using Unity, KDE, Gnome and other environments also have their own APIs on top. In short, it's a mess.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you budi, what’s the best way on macos or linux ?